# How can display one or more details in one component - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have main Tabs "Categories" and I want when I click to any one of them it will just appeared his Details,

so I'm decleare a flag to every category and update it when clicked to display category details, **BUT** I think this is a wrong idea! and other issue when I click to first category it's appear his details, but when I clicked other Category from the tabs, the first category it's still around!
So how can I handle these issue?

[Snack Here](https://snack.expo.io/r1GcUKhBS)

Here's my Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    open:true,
    cat2:false,
    cat3:false,
    cat4:false,
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}} >
                <ScrollView style={{flexGrow: 0.05, backgroundColor: '#347ed8', paddingTop: 50}} horizontal>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({open:!this.state.open})} style={{width: 100}}><Text style={{color:"#fff",fontSize:18}}>cat1 </Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={()=>this.setState({
                      cat2:!this.state.cat2
                      })} 

                    style={{width: 100}}><Text style={{color:"#fff",fontSize:18}}>Cat2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 100}}><Text style={{color:"#fff",fontSize:18}}>Cat3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 100}}><Text style={{color:"#fff",fontSize:18}}>Cat4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 100}}><Text style={{color:"#fff",fontSize:18}}>Cat5</Text></TouchableOpacity>



                </ScrollView>
                <View style={{flex: 0.95, backgroundColor: '#ddd'}}>

                {this.state.open && <View>
                  <Text>Category Details  One Here</Text>
                </View>}

                 {this.state.cat2 && <View>
                  <Text>Category Details Two Here!</Text>
                </View>}
                 {this.state.cat3 && <View>
                  <Text>Category Details Three Here!</Text>
                </View>}
                 {this.state.cat4 && <View>
                  <Text>Category Details four Here!</Text>
                </View>}


                  </View>
            </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to do what you want is to use a `React-navigation` module.

This problem should be that you have not set up touch events elsewhere, and the values shown by setting the conditions for touch events are different. However, this condition can mess up your code, which can be handled simply using the '`React-navigation`' module.

You can [use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)

**Example**

```js
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator,//React navigation version 4 and before
  createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';  //React navigation version 4 

//import Navigator in our project

import FirstPage from './pages/FirstPage';
import SecondPage from './pages/SecondPage';
//Making TabNavigator which will be called in App StackNavigator
//we can directly export the TabNavigator also but header will not be visible
//as header comes only when we put anything into StackNavigator and then export
const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: FirstPage },
    Settings: { screen: SecondPage },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      inactiveTintColor: '#F8F8F8',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#633689',
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: '#87B56A',
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
      },
    },
  }
);

//making a StackNavigator to export as default
const App = createStackNavigator({
  TabScreen: {
    screen: TabScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#633689',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
      title: 'TabExample',
    },
  },
});
```

[image: Exam]

Comment: That's a good solution really, I have some other Q, if I want to create something like this ? how can ? any ideas? the image when focused it's scale "W/H" and other items No ? https://imgur.com/yeSm0ZD

Comment: @OliverD It cannot be posted here. This is because the answer does not fit the question. If you want to solve this, check my answers with arrows and 'V' signs, then create and post a new question.

Comment: @OliverD To explain simply in the comments, you can change it by using animation or by changing the status value.